# Adding an orphaned commit to an existing branch in git

Tags: git

Say I have an orphaned commit and want to recover it. So far, I've always been doing it like this:

> git checkout -b newBranch

I always have to create a new branch just for this. Is there a way to add it to an existing branch (and avoid creating this throwaway one).

If not, why not?

Comment: A waste of time. I usually do this after accidentally leaving a commit orphaned. I want it back to the branch it belongs.

Comment: Could use some more context and details, it's not clear what you're problem is and what you're trying to do to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the commit hash, instead of:

```
git checkout -b new-branch 123abc
```

You can use:

```
git checkout existing-branch
git cherry-pick 123abc
```

The commit hash can be retrieved by looking at `git log`.

Comment: Those two incantations don't do the same thing at all. The first one creates a new branch pointer pointing at an existing (but possibly orphaned) commit. The second one determines the differences introduced by that commit relative to it's parent, and attempts to apply those changes to a (probably unrelated) branch.

Comment: @twalberg The given commands are indeed not exactly the same, I was assuming a single commit that you want to get into another branch. If you have a set of commits, you probably want to use `git merge`, as in `git checkout existing-branch && git merge 123abc`. (`git cherry-pick` can also work on a set of commits, but `git merge` allows for cleaner conflict resolution by creating a separate merge commit)